# Has Facebook deprecated the /EVENT_ID/invited part of their API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to figure out how to access the guest list data of an event on Facebook and the example given in the Facebook documentation located at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/ is:

https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435/invited

However, when I test this in the explorer I get:

```
{
  "error": "Request failed"
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: No, it’s of course not deprecated (that they would have announced previously as usual). Looks like the request fails due to large number of invitees – the request as shown fails for me in the Graph API Explorer as well, but [once I add a `limit=5`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=331218348435%2Finvited%3Flimit%3D5) it displays results as expected. (Higher limits, f.e. 500, work as well. You can try to figure out how high you can go, after that you will have to use paging.)

Comment: @cbr - any request specifying the limit parameter will include the pagination links in the response.

Comment: Yes … did I say different?

Comment: @cbr - I guess not. It sounded like you were saying use limit *otherwise* use paging. Misunderstanding I guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint is most definitely **not deprecated**.

The problem here is that there are simply too many people invited to that event! There are too many results to return in a single query...

If you specify a limit you will get the results you need:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435/invited?limit=10
```

The response for that request would be something like this :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "xxx", 
      "rsvp_status": "attending", 
      "id": "111"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "yyy", 
      "rsvp_status": "attending", 
      "id": "222"
    }, 
    ... (8 more results) ...
  ],
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435/invited?limit=10&offset=10&__after_id=29606639"
  }
}
```

Note that there is a `paging` result returned as well - this is the URL you will need to query in order to get the next batch of results. It uses the `limit` parameter and also the `offset` parameter to ensure that you don't get duplicate results.

---

In my example, I've given a limit of 10 users per response, but I've managed to get data even when specifying 1000 results. The bigger the limit you provide the longer the request will take to return data.